# Bind to multiple class names with Laravel & Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-6

I have a vue component that displays a list of items. I can flag any item as "active" (boolean value). That value is saved to a database.

For example, I could have five total items. Three of them could be marked as "active" the remaining two are not.

When my page loads, the active/not active data is coming from my controller and I am passing data to my vue component as a property. The property has an attribute `active` that can be toggled on/off. That value is stored in a database as a boolean.

This is what my component looks like:

```
<template>
    <div class="item" :class="{'active' : isActive}" @click="handleClick($event, item)">
        <div v-if="item.icon" class="item-icon">
            <i :class="item.icon"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="item-title">
            {{ item.title }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Item',
        data() {
            return {
                isActive: false,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            async handleClick(event, item) {
                try {
                    let response = await axios.patch(`/path/${item.id}`, {
                        title: item.title,
                        active: !this.isActive,
                    });

                    if (response.status === 200) {
                        this.isActive = !this.isActive;
                        console.log('isActive: ', this.isActive);
                    } else {
                        console.error('Error: could not update item. ', response);
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error: sending patch request. ', error);
                }
            },
        },
        props: {
            item: {
                type: Object,
                required: true,
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

Overall, the system is working. My request(s) are getting handled correctly and data is getting updated correctly.

If I change my template to this:

```
<div class="item" :class="{'active' : isActive}"
     @click="handleItemClick($event, item)">
```

I am seeing the class/ui update correctly. But, because the initial data is coming from Laravel (controller) I need to have the two classes.

So somehow I am not binding to the classes correctly so that when I click, the ui is getting updated correctly.

**EDIT**

Thank you so much for your suggestions. I updated my component logic to reflect what is working properly. When things fall apart is when I change the template to account for if an item is already active:

```
<div class="item" :class="{'active' : isActive, 'active': item.active}"
     @click="handleClick($event, item)">
```

The logic still works (when I refresh the page) but the UI doesn't update dynamically.

Comment: `:class="{ active: isActive || item.active }"` perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I want to thank everyone for their suggestions; it was a tremendous help!

I hope that I can help others with this so here is what I came up with.

```
<template>
    <div class="item" :class="{'active': isActive}"
         @click="handleClick($event, item)">
        <div v-if="item.icon" class="item-icon">
            <i :class="item.icon"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="item-title">
            {{ item.title }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Item',
        data() {
            return {
                isActive: this.item.active,  // <-- this was my error
            }
        },
        methods: {
            async handleClick(event, item) {
                try {
                    let response = await axios.patch(`/path/${item.id}`, {
                        title: item.title,
                        active: !this.isActive,
                    });

                    if (response.status === 200) {
                        this.isActive = response.data.item.active;
                    } else {
                        console.error('Error: could not update item. ', response);
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error: sending patch request. ', error);
                }
            },
        },
        props: {
            item: {
                type: Object,
                required: true,
            },
        },
    }
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a computed property that accounts for the `item.active` and for `isActive` in your component, like:

```
computed: {
  bindActive() {
    return this.isActive || this.item.active;
  }
}
```

So you can setup only one class in your template syntax:

```
<div class="item" :class="{'active' : bindActive}"  @click="handleItemClick($event, item)">...</div>
```

Comment: yeah, I'm so use to the class api :-/

Comment: Only thing that comes to mind is if `item` comes from a loop, eg `v-for="item in items"`. If so, OP won't be able to use a computed property

Comment: Thank you so much! I think this is close. The issue I believe I am struggling with is that I can't set `isActive: false,` for everything. Since the item could be already active, by setting the data attribute to `false`, vue thinks everything is inactive by default. Is there such a thing as dynamically setting the data attribute?

Comment: Well, you can change the `isActive` variable at any time -- in fact you do it in your code. You want it to be active by default, and switch to false only and only if the item (when it comes from the api call) has `active` as false?

Comment: Correct. If the item comes back as active from the api, then I need to set `isActive` to `false`. But, if another item comes back from the api as (not active), then I need to set `isActive` to `true`.

When my page loads, the vue component is getting populated from a controller - which has all the data (active or not) for each item.